# Static Website No Titles But Still Nav

Tags: pages, page-template, navigation, loop, static-website

So I have a static paged website and I want to make pages without title, but I still need the titles for the navigation to pick it up. How can I get rid of the Page.php (the_post()) from displaying the page title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your page.php template will be a tag containing `the_title()`, and that's what you have to delete. In my Wordpress theme, for example, the code looks like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="entry">
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <div class="post-meta">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

That last line is the one you need to get rid of.  You can simply delete it and the post title will be removed from all Pages.

**Note:** If you have a theme like Twenty Eleven that does not contain the `<?php the_title(); ?>` tag inside page.php, you'll have to follow the clues from page.php to find out where the template is coming from.  In the case of Twenty Eleven, page.php simply contains

```
<?php the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
```

and no template tags at all.  The clue is the get_template_part(): that tells us that page.php is pulling from a file called content-page.php. Look in the Twenty Eleven folder and you'll find content-page.php there for your editing pleasure. And sure enough, it contains this line:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Delete that and you're good to go.

Comment: haha thanks! Why would they split that little code into 2 files that's just over complicated IMO.